# Any faster methods to find data?

Tags: c, algorithm

This is an *Interview* question.

We are developing a k/v system, part of it has been developed, we need you to finish it.

**Things already done -**

1) Return a hash of any string, you can assume return value is always unique, no collision,
     it's up to you to use it or not

```
int hash(char *string);
```

**Things you have to finish -**

```
int set(char *key, char *value);
char *get(char *key);
```

And my answer was

```
struct kv {
        int key;
        char *value;
        kv *next;
};                  

struct kv *top;
struct kv *end;

void set(char *key, char *value) {
        if(top == NULL) {
                top = malloc(struct kv);
                end = top;
        }       
        sturct kv *i = top;
        int k = hash(key);
        while(i != end) {
                if(i->key == k) {
                        i->value = value;
                        return;
                }
                i = i->next;
        }
        i = malloc(struct kv);
        i->key = k;
        i->value = value;
        end = i;
}       

char *get(char *key) {
        if(top == NULL) {
                return NULL;
        }
        sturct kv *i = top;
        int k = hash(key);
        while(i != end) {
                if(i->key == k) {
                        return i->value;
                }       
                i = i->next;
        }       
        return NULL;
}
```

**Q:** - Is there any faster way to do it? What do you think is the fastest way?

Comment: You should look into HashMap/HashTables. They are probably the answer you're looking for.

Comment: `table[hash(key)]=value;` and return `table[hash(key)]` is what you are looking for.

Comment: I can't think better than this - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java

Comment: @roottraveller - Check my answer. There's more out there. :)

Comment: How many k/v pairs do you need to deal with.  For most systems, the answer must be less than 2^32 since your perfect hash function probably only returns that many different values — but are we talking about hundreds, thousands, millions or billions of keys?  That will impact your work.  If the interviewer didn't tell you, it is legitimate to ask.   Interviewers are expecting to get sensible questions to clarify the specification. You could check that the `int` is a 32-bit quantity too.  Interviewers deliberately don't tell you everything to see what you'll ask about.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but your solution is about the worse one can think of, in terms of efficiency.

Comment: Question number 1 is to ask them wth a "k/v system" is? It's not a formal term. I would guess it means key-value pair... but people who invent even more stupid abbreviations for the computer industry needs to get shot down.

Comment: @Lundin: ok with that but I wouldn't blame "the computer industry". I'd rather blame a guy posting such a question without wondering if he will be understood.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is made a linked list to store the key value pairs. But as you can see, the search complexity is `O(n)`. You can make it faster by creating a hash table. You already have a hash function with guaranteed 0 collisions.

What you can do is

```
char* hash_tables[RANGE_OF_HASH] = {NULL}; // Your interviewer should provide you RANGE_OF_HASH
```

Then your `set` and `get` become -

```
void set(char* key, char* value) {
    hash_table[hash(key)] = value; // Can do this because no collisions are guaranteed. 
}

char* get(char* key) {
    return hash_table[hash(key)];
}
```

In this case since you don't have to iterate over all the keys inserted, the `get` complexity is `O(1)` (also `set`).

But you need to be aware that this usually occupies more space than your approach.
Your method occupies `O(n)` space but this occupies `O(RANGE_OF_HASH)`. Which might not be acceptable in situations where memory is a constraint.

If `RANGE_OF_HASH` is very huge(like `INT_MAX`) and you don't have enough memory for hash_table, you can create a multi level hash table.

For instance, your main `hash_table` will have only `256` slots. Each of the entry will point to another hash table of 256 entries and so on. You will have 
to do some bit masking to get the hash value for each level. You can allocate each level on demand basis. This way you will minimize the memory usage.

Comment: There is no RANGE_OF_HASH, or it is MAX_INT

Comment: @yaminunaz `MAX_INT` is "okay" value for `RANGE_OF_HASH` But the size required by `hash_table` would be very high. Generally an operating system should be able to provide this much memory. Because anyway you would be using very few table entries. Just make sure you don't manually initialize to 0. But use system allocated zero'd pages by declaring the hash_table as global or static.

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of great ways of doing this. Here's a small reading list, go through it. There's definitely more out there that I'm not aware of.

- Sorted list with [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) - Depending on the usage patterns, can be fast or slow to build, but lookups are guaranteed to be O(log(N)).
- [Hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) - fast, close to O(1) on average, O(N) in worst case for all operations.
- [Binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) - best case O(log(N)), worst case O(N).

  - [AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) - guaranteed O(log(N)) for all operations.
  - [Red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) - similar to AVL but trades off lookup speed for more inserting speed.
- [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) - True O(1) on all operations, at the expense of more memory usage.

After this, take a break, brace yourself, and delve into [this article about computer memory](https://lwn.net/Articles/250967/). This is already advanced stuff and will show you that sometimes a worse [big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) measure can actually perform better in real world scenarios. It's all down to what kind of data will there be and what the usage patterns are.

Comment: Not using the given perfect hash value is a waste and certainly not the answer expected by the interviewer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - Probably, but an answer which includes both the hash table AND the other options would be even more impressive.

Comment: Not for me. Would look like showing off your knowledge without discernment and failing to exploit the information given in the problem statement. There is no reason to switch to a less efficient solution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - Well, it depends on the context, of course. In the original interview, when asked to complete the C code, it's obvious that they're expecting to see a hashtable so do that. Afterwards, if you get to talk about it, you can mention these. Anyways, the OP asked `Is there any faster way to do it? What do you think is the fastest way?` - and this tries to answer that. This is not so much about this specific interview (which is over anyway) as about general knowledge.

Comment: Why do you suggest *slower* solutions ? And why answering a question you've not been asked ? This is a lack of focus. By the way, technically the solution that is expected is not a hash table, but a plain array.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - ... what? O_o The OP asks for other, faster ways, compared to his own approach. He uses a very basic linked list, so all of my suggestions are actually faster than his. And where did you come up with the idea that they expected a plain array? In fact, even if I was in that interview and had written a hash table, I wouldn't have used an array with 2 billion entries in it. That's just a waste of RAM and/or address space. I mean, it can be done on modern computers, yes, but it's hardly efficient.

Comment: Right, I forgot to say that I am not comparing to the OP's solution, which IMO is just ruled out, but to the solution called for by the interviewer. Of course we don't have all parameters (who said two billions ?), but it would be a pity to ignore the available perfect hash and trade it for an ordinary hash.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - Well, true, in this specific case there might be a more efficient solution, depending on the characteristics of the hash. Still, I perceive the OP's question ("Is there any faster way to do it?") to be a general question about the problem, not simply "What was expected of me here?"

Comment: My last comment: "you can assume return value is always unique" is not innocent.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - Yes, I noticed that too immediately as I read it. Frankly though, I don't know what to make of it. If I was in the interview, I would have asked more about it (like, what range the returned `int` value will be in, how much memory I can assume the machine to have, what is important, etc). Then I can create a fairy-tale solution for a fairy-tale problem. In real life however such a hash function is almost always impossible and memory is precious, so a traditional hashtable (with a relatively small number of buckets) is the way to go.